# What is the GLFW screen format for ffmpeg encoding?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, glfw

I have a program where I have a GLFW window and read that window using `glReadPixels(0, 0,window_width, window_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) Buffer);` then use that `Buffer` to encode a frame via ffmpeg. It works fine however the resolution is a bit low.

I tried changing bit-rates to no avail so I started experimenting with formats. Normally I'm using `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` in my encoder as my format since the data that comes from the glfw window is RGBA but this format result in the said low resolution video. The result video is a lot more pixelated than whats seen on the GLFW window.

What could be the optimal pixel format for reading GLFW window? Some formats straight up not work resulting in `Specified pixel format  yuyv422 is invalid or not supported` error.

And here is where I got that error from:

```c
ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &opt);
```

This line causes me to get `Specified pixel format  yuyv422 is invalid or not supported` error when I use something other than YUV420.

I also have this setting `#define SCALE_FLAGS SWS_BICUBIC` which im not sure what it does but may also cause my error. (Not likeliy since this comes after the line mentioned above, but I could just keep the format at YUV420 and change `SWS_BICUBIC` instead.)

I'm using ubuntu, ffmpeg, glfw and glad (GLSL) to render the texture writeen in the frames. I got the encoder from ffmpegs [muxing.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) example.

Edit: Using `AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA` also results in a similar error.

Edit: Here is my sample code where I convert `Buffer` to ffmepg format:

```cpp
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
...
void video_encoder::set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(AVFrame *frame, struct SwsContext *sws_context) {
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 4 * width };

    sws_context = sws_getContext(
            width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
            width, height, STREAM_PIX_FMT,
            SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);

    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb_data, in_linesize, 0,
            height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every codec supports every pixel format. There are several methods to find out which pixel format to use.

[AVCodec](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html) has a field named [pix_fmts](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html#ac2b97bd3c19686025e1b7d577329c250)

> array of supported pixel formats, or NULL if unknown, array is terminated by -1

Follow the links at the bottom called 'Referenced by ...' to get a better understanding on how to utilize this property.

When it comes to converting, finding the best pixel format is mandatory, have look at [avcodec_find_best_pix_fmt_of_list](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__misc__pixfmt.html#ga9e74b43a3433ccfe836814f0a6371aa0)

> Find the best pixel format to convert to given a certain source pixel format.

And scaling is a complete different story (many filtering options), as can be seen [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libsws.html).

But somehow i doubt, that your pixelated output solely results from the rescale (pixel conversion). Sometimes [postprocessing](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lpp.html) helps. Look at the variable [pp_help](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/postprocess_8c_source.html#l00578) on the available postprocessing filters.

---

**Hint**

Before programming with the ffmpeg api libraries, i recommend to store your OpenGl rendering into a sequence of high quality (lossless codec) images (e.g. bmp, tga, png and perhaps the easiest [ppm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), from the [Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) package and of course [SGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics_Image)). Then try to experiment with the tool ffmpeg until you have the desired results. After that go and implement the used options into your program.

---

Some useful links:
(if you want to understand the meaning of the fields of [AVCodecContext](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html))

- [H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [MPEG-4 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4)
- [High Efficiency Video Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding)
- [High Efficiency Video Coding (Standard)](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.265-202108-I!!PDF-E&type=items)

  - especially section 3. Definitions